# Install magick/summarytools

Tags: r, rstudio-server

I am trying to install `summarytools` for R studio server that I'm running. When I install `magick` I get this:

```
> install.packages("magick")
Installing package into ‘/home/osrs/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/magick_2.7.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4813424 bytes (4.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 4.6 MB

* installing *source* package ‘magick’ ...
** package ‘magick’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Package Magick++ was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `Magick++.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'Magick++' found
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lMagick++-6.Q16
--------------------------- [ANTICONF] --------------------------------
Configuration failed to find the Magick++ library. Try installing:
 - deb: libmagick++-dev (Debian, Ubuntu)
 - rpm: ImageMagick-c++-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 - csw: imagemagick_dev (Solaris)
 - brew imagemagick@6 (MacOS)
For Ubuntu versions Trusty (14.04) and Xenial (16.04) use our PPA:
   sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:cran/imagemagick
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -y libmagick++-dev
If Magick++ is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a Magick++.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
-------------------------- [ERROR MESSAGE] ---------------------------
<stdin>:1:10: fatal error: Magick++.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘magick’
* removing ‘/home/osrs/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/magick’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘magick’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpXngxMd/downloaded_packages’
```

I'm assuming I can't install `summarytools` because I'm getting this error upon installing `magick`.

Comment: And in turn you do not have the system package Magick++ that supports to magick-R-pkg.

Comment: There are older versions of summarytools that don't rely on magick. Check out https://github.com/dcomtois/summarytools/tree/0-8-9 -- or install with `devtools::install_github("dcomtois/summarytools", ref="0-8-9")`